# How do I get the 5th word in a string? Java

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string of a text document and I want to save the 124th word of that string in another string how would I do this? I assume it counts each "word" as a string of text in between spaces (including things like - hyphens).

Edit:
Basically what I'm doing right now is grabbing text off a webpage and I want to get number values next to a certain word. Like here is the webpage, and its saved in a string .....health 78 mana 32..... or something of the sort and i want to get the 78 and the 32 and save it as a variable

Comment: Here's an interesting thing. What is a word? Is `1337` also a word? Think about it deeply and define *your* rules. From then on it should be simple.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a string

```
String s = "...";
```

then you can get the word (separated by spaces) in the *n<sup>th</sup>* position using `split(delimiter)` which returns an array `String[]`:

```
String word = s.split("\\s+")[n-1];
```

**Note:**

- The argument passed to `split()` is the delimiter. In this case, `"\\s+"` is a *regular expression*, that means that the method will split the string on each whitespace, even if there are more than one together.

Answer (score 3):

Why not convert the String to a String array using StringName.split(" "), i.e. split the string based on spaces. Then only a matter of retrieving the 124th element of the array.

Comment: Make sure to add a little bit of example code for a better answer! Also, you *own* this answer. State it like a proud fact or correct approach, not as a comment/suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have a string like this:

```
String a="Hello stackoverflow i am Gratin";
```

To see 5th word, just write that code:

```
   System.out.println(a.split("\\s+")[4]);
```

Comment: how does this work? basically what i'm doing right now is grabbing text off a webpage and I want to get number values next to a certain word. Like here is the webpage, and its saved in a string .....health 78 mana 32..... or something of the sort and i want to get the 78 and the 32 and save it as a variable

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach that automatically returns a blank String if there *isn't* a 5th word:

```
String word = input.replaceAll("^\\s*(\\S+\\s+){4}(\\S+)?.*", "$1");
```

Solutions that rely on `split()` would need an extra step of checking the resulting array length to prevent getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there are less than 5 words.